# When using jackd audio and internal soundcard, sound is way too loud and gets clipped into noise

Tags: sound, jack

when using standard pulseaudio, my laptop plays audio just fine on both headphones and speakers. However some applications require jack, and although I can start jack fine I can not get sound with it when using the internal sound card. When using a USB card, jack works fine.

Jack with the internal sound is so loud the audio is just clipping. I need to adjust the volume to <10% to have good but way too loud sound. Otherwise it is just clipping and it sounds like white noise.
This seems like a driver parameter but I cannot find it...

this is the card info `pacmd list-cards`

```
index: 1
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 8
properties:
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "sof-hda-dsp"
    alsa.long_card_name = "sof-hda-dsp"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card1"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "06c8"
    device.string = "1"
    device.description = "sof-hda-dsp"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    HiFi: Play HiFi quality Music (priority 40768, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <HiFi>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_5__sink/#1: sof-hda-dsp HDMI3/DP3 Output
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_4__sink/#2: sof-hda-dsp HDMI2/DP2 Output
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_3__sink/#3: sof-hda-dsp HDMI1/DP1 Output
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink/#4: sof-hda-dsp Speaker + Headphones
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_5__sink.monitor/#1: Monitor of sof-hda-dsp HDMI3/DP3 Output
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_4__sink.monitor/#2: Monitor of sof-hda-dsp HDMI2/DP2 Output
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_3__sink.monitor/#3: Monitor of sof-hda-dsp HDMI1/DP1 Output
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink.monitor/#4: Monitor of sof-hda-dsp Speaker + Headphones
    alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__source/#5: sof-hda-dsp Headphones Stereo Microphone
    alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_6__source/#6: sof-hda-dsp Digital Microphone
ports:
[Out] HDMI3: HDMI3/DP3 Output (priority 700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
    properties:
        
[Out] HDMI2: HDMI2/DP2 Output (priority 600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
    properties:
        
[Out] HDMI1: HDMI1/DP1 Output (priority 500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
    properties:
        
[Out] Speaker: Speaker (priority 100, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
    properties:
        
[Out] Headphones: Headphones (priority 200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
    properties:
        
[In] Mic2: Headphones Stereo Microphone (priority 200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
    properties:
        
[In] Mic1: Digital Microphone (priority 100, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
    properties:
```

Comment: Have you tried alsamixer?

Comment: yes, I have to set it to like 8  (on a range from 0-100) do have unclipped sound... there is a multiplier problem somewhere